# I am not getting the exact log file after zipping it

Tags: objective-c, email, zip, logfile

I am getting a **log file**. I'm **zipping** that file and sending it in **email**. But when I **unzip** the file and view the **contents** the contents are totally different. I think it is in **encrypted** format. Or maybe I'm following wrong approach for **Zipping** a file and sending it in email.**I'm using objective-zip**. **I don't know how should I send it in email**.This is my code

-(void)mailLogFile {

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    NSDictionary *user = [[DBHelper getSharedInstance] getCurrentUser];
    NSString *propertyQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT RecentActivityId,PropertyPIC,PropertyId,Message,IsSynced,ActivityTime,ErrorCode,ErrorMessage,ErrorData,EntityId,TableNames From RecentActivity ORDER BY ActivityTime desc"];
    NSArray *resultArry = [[DBHelper getSharedInstance] getRecordsBySQL:propertyQuery];

    NSLog(@"This is the eNVDS in Recent Activity:%@" ,resultArry);
    [[DBHelper getSharedInstance] AddLogFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is the eNVDS in Recent Activity:%@" ,resultArry]];
    NSPredicate *notsynced = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"IsSynced == 0 || IsSynced == %@",@"0"];
    NSArray *notsyncedenvds = [resultArry filteredArrayUsingPredicate:notsynced];
    NSLog(@"This is the eNVDS in Recent Activity which is not synced:%@" ,notsyncedenvds);
    [[DBHelper getSharedInstance] AddLogFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is the eNVDS in Recent Activity which is not synced:%@" ,notsyncedenvds]];


    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *WritableDBPath= [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Logfile.txt"];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:WritableDBPath];

    OZZipFile *zipFile32= [[OZZipFile alloc] initWithFileName:WritableDBPath mode:OZZipFileModeCreate legacy32BitMode:YES];
        OZZipWriteStream *stream= [zipFile32 writeFileInZipWithName:@"Logfile.txt" compressionLevel:OZZipCompressionLevelBest];

      [stream writeData:data];
      [stream finishedWriting];



  [zipFile32 close];
    NSString *emailTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Log file of %@",[NSDate date]];
    NSMutableString *messageBody = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Login with %@",user[@"Username"]];
    if(![user[@"PropertyName"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])[messageBody appendFormat:@"\n%@",user[@"PropertyName"]];
    [messageBody appendFormat:@"\nApp version : %@",APP_VERSION];
    [messageBody appendFormat:@"\nPlease describe your problem scenario here."];
    [messageBody appendFormat:@"\n\n\nThanks"];

    NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"support@aglive.com"];


    MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mc setSubject:emailTitle];

    [mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
    [mc setToRecipients:toRecipents];


    [mc addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"application/zip" fileName:@"Logfile.zip"];


    [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:nil];

}else{

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Aglive Pro" message:@"You have not configured your mail account. Please configure your mail account from the device settings." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

}

And this is the contents of file which I'm receiving-

```
&Ø›¡íQÇ~ŸEüÒ∞f"ê√0´5CaÙô·O“ÁúZ/ó¿s•#ob!_}K£çx0ô@†‰Ë˙µè@+n |µé†ÇÂ2N—R|¨÷îúîq∞ƒG@0~PºßøÌ@´9Ú[Ä    D˙,Ò≈ÑäXπs˝#èõv30¸w‹
Ü;ùÓ* Ëè&à§∑T—0ô⁄˚ñB;u–˙$Í·/Q¡Yø#EHØ4™lø§äïtV>^=º[¸UgDG…Cnf¢ì˚†y¢ÍÙÿQX1¬˚çı±€·≥•ÉütÙ«—ïã@"\oKïÊ›:ÀÂ\œ˘"a]≤-o÷<Z‹ôù¸9%OœU∂˘3ëzsﬂ‹ı‰sHÉG£ZﬁY*•¶°âu¶€&“î—]ÛÈ¬∂Òa5˚⁄Ω>›_˙˝˙Å˙¬È•)J£497∞◊ÊzˇyvÂ>;Õ¥ë™£ﬁF9˙ÅªVÕUeö§ôVfÇo^¡8µs=4¿É‹SyUæó\ÉG
‚›ıëcÆÀﬂE^ır^m€7ı™oX)£@§Æ6⁄{öá◊|–≈ﬂç“Ú$6È`lP..*;•∂»b2S∑6‘Ènd(7◊E$ù‘%|o:¯’_#am   kt◊ÁÎ4Øp4,Ù\W*[K1…oπ3óŒ`ìóÍ†æ–£i'O4`62 ce«9‹∂À03¶«ﬂ?^)€D√7ˆœ–u˚º{kÓÆ»±R°ß{∏<G[7‘ék⁄∂‘6¯ªútL,rj˘É™„BÑ:∞†vÒ¡÷Eo◊pC%ìÄà3·m¨(R^¢R~Ø«æ†∏XÑZˇ)∆úz˘*≤P•g‡¸c≈1± ÈüÂv'≈Cöï§ï.ù‰pm∆)•|WGıË^†u∆éW›ß„å˜{xˆ_Hov5à°TAmªÒO∫1ÅGXiÈ.W-∞.F$≤p˚È˘8QOË}/œŒL
KW%y@&ZânH;ÀE:îaWÅÜk®Ë”‘ÆöfJÉ$≠Ê≈⁄ì>^ÍÃ_U¶>†èêé:-˛$î˜§"xﬁ@¥A⁄1∂„äWæƒø˜™Õ†ùRR®≤•(4ø Á•˘S7≤≥«FvígîK¨≠ˇ%C‚<KÓÙTXã≈⁄N˝tåcS’◊2†:i¨ŒªËØ˚Dá‚ˇ*Œ0Á•B   £-ígM8 ÁÇ')£çÑ€© ∂&¥Ú¬á◊-µ‰‘b?˝\} V Ë±d’µƒ2;è3ÀÈõ‘®ïQjAõ˛´’ÛeZÊ3.Nuü‚∫|ÂìZ"ëZ∏«
˙˛Æ.`Ææm¶ù"€î◊√D·‘ﬁAÉ}[≠≈0{e§o≈î    ’∫:uUDŸ|(ïÉ¥€”]Í¨Ù2¨6≥√√õôÿY ñ=rvÆ§9;ïOuÄ2SÄ9É8îi∆“?=´Ó[;<Èeåë¡`uwÿ’û8®wí8Ë«©‰LËj√_ Ωú¯/nÚb”£¸i|l÷©íë%7é‡dE≠Z…ûÌÿ?õ◊‘LÂNëC\W(fOãú◊ªﬂ.]Yö"…ÌAﬂ&ı„ß3D*{ÂÆH•ÛÊ˙ø«˘≠    ¶Ø™öåÔÆM.◊ßÎpê@KÀÂÜŸÑß;~EH‹Ìâ{$ üêXìsnãñ%∫
Ÿ!ç<ï 'EÉq«:ñ¶∞∏ÿâ:` 6]Úãã©„_"›iefB%«1”Jê˛ÄÜœ4«]bÂ}õÁh_«ë«é!‡´“ﬁ∏mîs„R!¸ÁñT˙⁄«*s=∏œ˘ÄÂ•5ç7Gàn"èÊ¿À⁄∂ñuSx25¶eâõººY˛B1
TÌxùÚ‹Y+08∆_(|JAﬁñ{Y∏¯˛*‹‹Á˝ÖóssZœ0„Ñeπ[≠F‚¥ø[«õˇ©à0ıåHôbÉS $˝‚¯Äù‰b
```

I should get the proper log file after **unzipping** it.I know I have to make change in this code

```
[mc addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"application/zip" fileName:@"Logfile.zip"];
```

Because here I sending the same data like before but I'm not able to send the zipFile32.How should I proceed from here?

Comment: Where do you make any attempt to zip the txt file?

Comment: @rmaddy I used Objective-zip but it was not working for me so I went with this approach. It would be helpful if u guide me which approach I should follow to zip the file and send it in email.

Comment: The code you posted makes no attempt to zip anything. `data` is just the plain old txt file but then you mistakenly claim it's a zip file and give it a zip extension but the attachment is still a plain old text file. You need a zip library and you need to actually zip the file. Then attach the data of the zip file.

Comment: @rmaddy Can u help me with the code please?

Comment: I have been struggling with this for two days.

Comment: [Edit] your question to include your attempted use at Objective-zip and explain what issues you are having with it.

Comment: @rmaddy I have edited my question just I need to know how should I add the  file attachment. That is where I'm facing issue. Ur help will be appreciated.